# How to covert array into json object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Dynamically I am getting an array.

like as
`var array = ['Name', 'example@gmail.com', '9011234XX']`
But I want like something this

`var jsonObj= {"name":"Name", "email":"example@gmail.com", "mob":"9011234XX"}`

Comment: you could destructure, then restructure into an object: https://jsfiddle.net/cogswfj5/

Comment: Do you mean something like `JSON.stringify(array)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can destructure your array and use those variables to create an object.

```js
var array = ['Name', 'example@gmail.com', '9011234XX'];

const [ name, email, mob ] = array;
// same as const name = array[0], email = array[1];

const requiredObject = { name, email, mob };
// same as { name: name, email: email, mob: mob }

console.log(JSON.stringify(requiredObject))
```